# How to resize the UITableView cell width

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How to resize the tableview cell width? I would like to add button in last cell, which is the normal `UIButton`. I add the button to the cell, but how can I resize that cell?

Google is failed to show that..

Comment: Please ask your questions properly with some code examples. Also make clear on which device your are developing and why you want to resize the cell's width. Is it when it activates edit mode?

Comment: Do you mean height? A UITableViewCell is always scaled to fit the width of it's UITableView

Comment: do you want to insert button on each cell?, then there is no need to make table size smaller, you can do it without doing it, am i right about your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to resize the textLabel of the cell, you can access it with cell.textLabel.  Change its frame.

Comment: not like that buddy i want to add small button in last cell but that cell should be of width small size